# Guardar datos de un select en la bdd

Tags: php, html, css

```
<legend><h3>FORMULARIO</h3></legend>
<form md="post" action="agregarDatos.php" name="formulario" id="formulario"  onSubmit="return limpiar()">
                <div>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Supervisor de turno</td>
                            <td>
                                <select type="text" id="supervisorTurno" name="supervisorTurno" class="inputs" required="true" >
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Selecccionar</option>
                                    <option value="">A</option>
                                    <option value="">B</option>
                                    <option value="">C</option>
                                    <option value="">D</option>
                                    <option value="">E</option>                                     
                                    <option value="">F</option>
                                    <option value="">G</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Fecha procedimiento</td>
                            <td><input  type="date" id="fecha" name="fecha" class="inputs" required="true"/></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Hora procedimiento</td>
                            <td><input  type="time" id="hora" name="hora" class="inputs" required="true" /></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Ingreso Llamada</td>
                            <td>
                                <select  type="text" id="ingresoLlamada" name="ingresoLlamada" class="inputs" required="true">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccionar</option>
                                    <option value="">Línea 800</option>
                                    <option value="">WhatsApp</option>
                                    <option value="">Radio</option>
                                    <option value="">Celular</option>                                       
                                    <option value="">Terreno</option>
                                    <option value="">Línea 1426</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Nombre Operador</td>
                            <td><input  type="text" id="nombreOperador" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" name="nombreOperador" class="inputs" required="true"  onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)" maxlength="25" pattern=".{5,25}"  title="Debe escribir nombre y apellido"/></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Tipo Procedimiento</td>
                            <td><input  type="text" id="tipoProcedimiento" name="tipoProcedimiento" class="inputs" required="true" maxlength="15"/></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Lugar Procedimiento</td>
                            <td><input  type="text" id="lugarProcedimiento" name="lugarProcedimiento" class="inputs" required="true" maxlength="15"/></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Móvil Concurre</td>
                            <td><input  type="text" id="movilConcurre" name="movilConcurre" class="inputs" required="true" maxlength="15"/></td>
                        </tr>   

                        <tr>
                            <td>A cargo Móvil</td>
                            <td><input  type="text" id="aCargoMovil" name="aCargoMovil" class="inputs" required="true" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)" maxlength="15"/></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Hora llegada al lugar</td>
                            <td><input  type="time" id="horaLlegada" name="horaLlegada" class="inputs" required="true" /></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Hora Término</td>
                            <td><input  type="time" id="horaTermino" name="horaTermino" class="inputs" required="true" /></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Nombre Víctima</td>
                            <td><input  type="text" id="nombreVictima" name="nombreVictima" class="inputs" required="true" placeholder="Nombre completo" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)"  maxlength="25" pattern=".{5,50}"  title="Debe escribir nombre completo"/></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Nombre Paramédico</td>
                            <td><input  type="text" id="nombreParamedico" name="nombreParamedico" class="inputs" required="true" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)"  maxlength="25" pattern=".{5,25}"  title="Debe escribir nombre y apellido"/></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Vehículo de Emergencia concurre</td>
                            <td><input  type="text" id="vehiculoEmergenciaConcurre" name="vehiculoEmergenciaConcurre" class="inputs" required="true" maxlength="25"/></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>A cargo Vehículo</td>
                            <td><input  type="text" id="aCargoVehiculo" name="aCargoVehiculo" class="inputs" required="true" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)" maxlength="25" placeholder="Persona a cargo"/></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Resultado Procedimiento</td>
                            <td><input  type="text" id="resultadoProc" name="resultadoProc" class="inputs" required="true" maxlength="15"/></td>
                        </tr>

                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td><textarea required="true" id="informe" name="informe" maxlength="500" rows="10" cols="37" placeholder="Informe Paramédico" ></textarea></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                            <input type="submit" onSubmit="" value="Guardar" name="opcion" style="float:left;margin-top: 6px;" />

                    </table>
                </div>


            </form>
```

Hola, Tengo el siguiente problema, ojalá puedan ayudarme.
Al guardar los campos de un formulario, el campo "ingreso llamada" queda guardado vacío en la bdd.Me pasa lo mismo con varios campos select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola amigo en el atributo value de los options te hace falta el valor lo tienes vacíos value=""

Comment: Eso era  jajaja, muchas gracias.

Comment: jaja de nada, bueno si jaja da la pregunta como cerrada.

Comment: ¿Cómo se cierra una pregunta?

Comment: dala como mejor respuesta

Answer (score -2):

guardar.php

alert("Si fue guardado");
                     ';

            }else{
                    '
                        alert("no fue guardado");
                     ';
            }
        //Cerramos la conexion con la base de datos 
        mysqli_close($conexion);        
    ?>